# TCPClient - Send and Receive Overlapping

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am working on a client-server application.

I use TCPClient for both server and client.

Server listens and responds and the client will send and receive.  Each respond from the server contains different message length.

The client has 2 request. One is ping request and the other is sending data request.

I created a thread to ping the server every 10 seconds.

The data request is send by the client when a user presses the send button.

The server responds to the ping request by sending 2 bytes back to client.

The server responds to the data request by sending back 8 bytes.

Here's the problem that I am running into.

The ping thread would at times send the request to the server at the same time that a user presses the send button.

Now the data request method is reading from the socket and expecting 8 bytes but only getting 2 bytes thus hang for a long time.

here's the snippet from data request method:

```
byteBuffer = new byte[8];
remainingBytes = byteBuffer.Length;
numberOfBytesRead = netStream.Read(byteBuffer, index, remainingBytes);
```

here's the snippet from ping thread:

```
byteBuffer = new byte[2];
remainingBytes = byteBuffer.Length;
numberOfBytesRead = netStream.Read(byteBuffer, index, remainingBytes);
```

What can I do so that the client knows which response goes to which method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need:

1. A single thread reading everything.
2. An identifier on the front of each message: REQUEST or PING.

The reading thread reads one byte, decides which it is, reads as many more bytes are required, and responds.